# Making an "input" button text non editable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using a javascript dictionary to create an assignment list, there are two elements: text (the title) and text2 (a hash anchor link)

```
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "viewButton";
    element2.value = todoDictionary["text"];
    var link= todoDictionary["text2"];
    element2.id = rowID;
    element2.setAttribute("onclick","window.location.hash = link");
    element2.className = "viewButton";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
```

When the list is diplayed, when I click on the item title, it temporarily brings up the keyboard before going to the link. I assume it's because it is an "input" item. I tried "label" and "text area" instead of "input" in the document.createElement, but the title doesn't show. 
any way to make it so it's still a button but the title isn't editable?

EDIT:
New issue @david thomas
When I change the element type to button, it now ignores the "viewButton" css that I have put into the file. On first launch, it keeps the proper style. On second launch, it defaults to the jquery CSS. But if I add new items, they come in the right style.

if I leave the element type to "viewButton" the style stays, but it also allows editing of the text.

I had this style issue happen before, which I fixed by adding the "viewButton" style to the jquery CSS. 
[CSS style not sticking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413611/css-style-not-sticking)

Any ideas on how to override the style?

Noel

Answer (score 2):

Why you use `element2.type = "viewButton"`? Try `type="submit"` or `<button>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine the problem is that the `type` is invalid, and therefore the `input` is being rendered as a text-`input` instead (unless there's more JavaScript or jQuery happening elsewhere to remedy that?).

That said, you could simply use:

```
// set the element to a button type:
element2.type = 'button';
// prevent the element from being able to receive focus:
element2.readonly = true;
```

Though if you *want* a button, you might as well create a `button` element:

```
var element2 = document.createElement('button');
```

References:

- [HTML `input` element (look at the valid values for the `type` attribute)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).
- [States of the `type` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#states-of-the-type-attribute).

Comment: Thank you both, that was the issue. I was using "viewButton" as it was in the code that someone else had used that I was adapting to my use. 
I suppose there isnt a way to have both be the answer to this question? 


Noel

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant

```
element2.type = "button"
```

I found this SO question about the "button" type:
[<button> vs. <input type="button" />. Which to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469059/button-vs-input-type-button-which-to-use)

Comment: New issue @david thomas When I change the element type to button, it now ignores the "viewButton" css that I have put into the file. On first launch, it keeps the proper style. On second launch, it defaults to the jquery CSS. But if I add new items, they come in the right style.

if I leave the element type to "viewButton" the style stays, but it also allows editing of the text.

I had this style issue happen before, which I fixed by adding the "viewButton" style to the jquery CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20413611/css-style-not-sticking
Any ideas on how to override the style?

Noel